# Having Trouble using env variables in Next.js

Tags: next.js

Converted my react application to next.js and trying to add my env.local files to my next.js application but it is not working.

I tried: adding env.local to the root of my folder and also looked at the documentation along with restarting my server

[documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables)

```
SERVICE_ID ="default_service"
USER_ID = "user_ra9adakLqa47SSFhb4QI3Swp"
TEMPLATE_ID ="template_xocwssd1upm"

console.warn(process.env.USER_ID)
await emailjs.send(
    process.env.SERVICE_ID,
    process.env.TEMPLATE_ID,
    templateParams,
    process.env.USER_ID
);
```

undefined

An user-id is required

Comment: Where are you using them, on the server side or client side?

Comment: Im not sure im using them to send a contact form

Comment: the email.js needs it to send the email so I guess server?

Comment: In the contact form you mean like inside some React component?

Comment: Yes inside a react component

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables would i do this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use env variables on the client (in your React components) then you need to [prefix them](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`, or use [older way](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables) of exposing them to the client inside `next.config.js`.

Comment: Now this is only working on localhost and not on the server

Comment: `env.local` files works on for local dev. You need `env.production` file for production server